# Can't use sequence operator `...` on a separate line in Raku

Tags: raku

The following code works:

```
my @fibo = 1, 1, -> $a, $b { $a + $b } ...  *;
say @fibo[^10];
```

output:

```
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```

But if you split this over multiple lines like this:

```
my @fibo = 1,
           1,
           -> $a, $b { $a + $b }
           ...
           *;
say @fibo[^10];
```

it gives an error:

```
*
  in block <unit> at ./dotdotdot line 4
```

It appears that the `...` is interpreted as the yada-operator in this case.  But it shouldn't, should it?  Both versions of the code should be equivalent.  (This isn't Python, whitespace should be mostly irrelevant.)

As a workaround, the following does work correctly:

```
my @fibo = 1,
           1,
           -> $a, $b { $a + $b } ...
           *;
say @fibo[^10];
```

(Of course, this is a very artificial example, but I found this when [using a much more complicated sequence](https://github.com/mscha/aoc/blob/master/aoc2023/aoc10bb) that's too long to put on one line.)

Tested up to 2023.11.

Comment: Raku has a very simple unforgiving rule that if the last thing in a line of code is a block that would make sense as the end of a statement then it's the end of a statement. There are many solutions, such as the one you suggested, or adding a `\\` after the closing curly brace, but that's the deal. After you hit this problem a couple times, you'll find that when you subsequently try to type such code, or see a related error message and think "WTF?", your friend [ERNie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-related_negativity) will stop you in your tracks and you'll think "Oh, right" and fix it.

Comment: Thanks, @raiph!  If you could put this in an answer, I'll accept it.  (And I now use your `\ ` suggestion, since putting the `...` on a separate line makes it much clearer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raku has a very simple unforgiving rule that if the last thing in a line of code is a block that would make sense as the end of a statement then it's the end of a statement. There are many solutions, such as the one you suggested, or adding a `\` after the closing curly brace. -raiph